# How do I do meditation?

Tags: meditation

Can anybody help me with meditation? I tried the sitting posture and concentrating on my breath. But in my mind I get lot of inner chatting.

Please suggest me some way to do it correctly.

Comment: Try chanting Gayatri Mantra.

Comment: While breathing in speak ooooooooo and while breathing out speak mmmmmmm that will help you to concentrate on breathing without other thoughts To know more about **om** you can check out this [blog]( http://gayatriclab.com/2012/04/the-secret-of-om-mantra-meditation/)

Comment: Yes that is meditation! Meditation is not like: 'sit in one posture and suddenly miracles start happening and you realize God'. It will take time. It is good that your Mind is having lots of inner chatting. Sit for five minutes, then increase to six, and so on gradually!! With time everything will cease and God will reveal Himself. We sadhakas have been conditioned through many births to only think about ourself and about the world. Then how will we suddenly quiet the mind in one second. It takes time. Everything requires practice. Do not give up. Keep up the good work! All the best! Good q!

Comment: Sit in siddha or padmasana do achman, take a deep breath do pranayam 3 times, by heart some specific mangalacharan mantras or just something like hanuman chalisa or sankatnashan ganeshstora or similar things which clears the atmosphere around you and also your mind these are purification process, then sit in meditation in siddhasana or padmasana let mind chatter be there, you be on your position then relax everything let everything go with your breath and then without fully sleeping or being fully awake just go in between sleep and wakefullness....

Comment: you aren't unconscious like falling asleep or not  fully conscious of external stimuli don't let anything I literally mean 'anything' bother you. Just remain in that state, relaxed but not asleep and just be there grasp everything but don't notice anything. As for japa if you have time and gyatri deeksha (yagnopavit) you can do gyatri or else you should perform another japa like a gurumantra if you have guru or simply omkar if nothing comes up. While doing japa do it with breath not by speaking mildly or loudly it is known as manas japa and it's best form of japa helps in meditation

Comment: @Sai Aleister Crowley, in his work [Book 4](http://hermetic.com/crowley/book-4/aba1.html), recommends keeping a stopwatch and timing how long it takes for your mind to wander.

Comment: The first step is to find your teacher. The next steps are: hearing (s̒ravanam), then reflecting (mananam), and finally meditating (nididhyāsanam)

Comment: See Lord Krishna's comment in Gita 4.34

Comment: And His more detailed answer on how to meditate in Uddhava Gita Chapter 9.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That is an interesting approach!

Comment: First of all thanks to all of you. @Sai I stated my process long away . I am willing to restart again but do not want to trap such a different ways. I will follow only one and that need to be practiced.

Comment: @uttamjaiswal Yes why to change your way of meditation. I did not ask you to change your current style of meditation. I was saying you must continue the same with more vigors effort and confidence. I was saying that if you are currently doing for 10 minutes, slowly increase the time span gradually. Straight away one cannot control the Mind, which is the source of this Maya. One needs constant practice. Swami Vivekananda's famous quote "Arise, Awake and Stop Not till the Goal is reached". There is absolutely no need to change you current style. All the best. Good q

Answer (score 1):

Meditation basically needs concentration. You can focus on your breath, Or concentrate on repeating a word or mantra.  For a beginner it is not possible to sit continuously for hours. You can increase your concentration by focusing a candle flame.

It will be difficult in starting to make your mind peaceful. Let the thoughts come and go. Don't try to force your mind stop thinking. It will not work. Start to meditate for some minutes and slowly increase your time. You will get the result slowly because it is not an instant process.

Comment: Welcome to Hi.SX. We encourage you to cite sources from scriptures.

Comment: Meditation does not need concentration.