# How to focus on third eye while meditating?

Tags: meditation

My question is simple. others find it duplicate but still it's unique in terms of meditations next level.

I read that, for meditation, there are many different ways to stay focused.

e.g. focusing on breath, third eye, heart beat etc..

But, while meditating I can't find anything like third eye or any part of it.

So, what's the base?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the meditation techniques found in the scriptures?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/519/what-are-the-meditation-techniques-found-in-the-scriptures)

Comment: @sv. The question is not on meditation techniques but on how to focus.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I initially wanted to link to [How do I do meditation?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9746/2995) but that is closed as dup. of the one I linked earlier. And isn't 'how to focus' a meditation technique? :)

Comment: this is the classic example of experience vs belief. Without jumping in the water, you cannot swim. Without having swimmed, how do you  get the courage to jump in the water? Similarly, without having meditated, you dont know where or what is third eye, however without knowing that how can you meditate on it? You have to draw a line somewhere. Either go with something you are comfortable and you can relate to (like a flame or a picture of God), or take a leap of faith and imagine the third eye with the belief that it shall be revealed eventually! Good luck :)

Comment: @sv. In my opinion, 'how to focus' is one of the many myths floating about meditation. Hence, it deserves a separate question. This is usually believed by people who have not begun meditation and/or have just read about it.

Comment: @Sai: thanks, but if a person swimming from last 5-6 years and still not get, where is it ends then what? i also used flame and a point to get more focused, in our language it's called TRATAK, i comfortable with that but is there any thing else you want to share, more deeper...

Comment: @Bharat Ok, thanks for clarifying. It looks like your question has been answered, so I'm happy that you have found what you're looking for :). Dont give up and keep up the good work. All the best'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not focus in meditation. It is the exactly opposite of that. Meditation is not concentration, it is de-concentration. You just have to relax. Ofcourse, high energy is needed to be able to relax, hence it is preceded by Pranayama and Kriya Yoga.

> Q – What is Meditation?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar – Many believe that meditation is concentration
>   or that it takes a lot of effort. Meditation is not concentration. It
>   is the opposite of concentration. If you have to drive anywhere, you
>   need concentration. If you simply have to relax at home, there need
>   not be any effort. You don’t need concentration.
>
> Meditation is deep relaxation and no concentration. So, if thoughts
>   come during meditation, we do not try to chase them. The more we chase
>   them, the more they come. If you want to get rid of a thought, it will
>   not be easy. It will come back in a stronger way.
>
> So, we have another strategy. If bad thoughts come to us, we hug them,
>   we shake hands with them. Then, they disappear. If good thoughts come,
>   we give them a hug, then they become quiet. We do not try to stop any
>   thoughts, it’s an effortless practice.

Taken from: http://www.artofliving.org/meditation/srisri-meditation/sound-to-silence

I was lucky to be introduced to meditation at the age of 17. I would recommend that rather than doing it on your own, you learn it from a proper teacher. There are many such good organisations teaching meditation - Art of Living foundation, Isha Yoga foundation etc.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is not entirely true. There are two types of meditation - contemplative and concentrative. Buddhism explains this better.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Sorry, I do not agree with you. I assume that you meditate?

Comment: thanks amit that helps me lot, i also lucky as like u in terms of meditation starting, but i follow OSHO rajnish, still i also listen all other gurus too. now i have long experience of just relaxing while meditation, yes my memory and inner peace become stronger, but what i need is the next level of mediatiaion, do you have any words on it? please share..

Comment: @Bharat Hi Bharat, lets chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39774/discussion-on-meditation

Comment: @AmitSaxena i dont know but i can't add any msg in chating..

Comment: @Bharat I changed the access, try now..